# Почему некорректно отображается svg иконка?

Tags: html, css

[image: Изображение]

Отображает только 2 основных цвета, экспортировал с фигмы. Вставляю через img

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

варианты решений:

1. посмотри тип файла картинки
2. разрешено только читать или скрытое - это иногда влияет
3. картинка по размеру не та
4. путь написал неправильный, слэш в обратную сторону поставил
5. версия html не та
6. в head напутал что-то
7. в помощь тебе сайт html5css.ru